# Making All possible combinations list from a smaller list in python

Tags: python, list, combinations

While making an app I tried to think in a way to collect all the possible orders and combinations of an unknown length list in python.
As an example, I have a list

`[1, 2]`

I want a way to make as an example list like this

`[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 2], [2, 1, 1], [2, 1, 2], [2, 2, 1] [2, 2, 2]]`

Yes I want a a bigger combination of list with all possible order and all with the same length as the example above

I was trying to find a way to do that but almost all of my ways ends in **time run error** So it would be helpful if anyone could help me and thanks

Comment: `almost all of my ways ends in time run error ` ..Can u pls attach the code that you getting errors?

Comment: probably with `itertools.product`

Comment: Is it possible by itertools.product to have a bigger lists

Comment: for instance : `list(itertools.product([1, 2],repeat=3))`

Comment: Or `list(itertools.product(*[smalllist]*n)` where smalllist is your starting list, and n the length of your 'combinations',

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I fixed the duplicate closure; the other question is only tangentially related.